# Javascript: Save content to Text File (No complicated Server stuff / HTTPRequest )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I am working on a small Project for myself. I wont upload a webpage but only run the files on localhost on my machine(HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT)

```
function saveData() {
        $.post("testFile.txt", "New Content of the File ");
    }


 function getData() {
        $.when($.get("testFile.txt")).done(function(requestedData) {
            alert(requestedData);
        });
    }
```

Ok so this is basically a dummy Project to explain my Problem.
The methods are called by two different Buttons with an "onclick" event.
First Button which calls "getData()" works fine. The testFile.txt is located right next to the Html and Javascript file, and the getData() method correctly alerts the content of the text file as a String.

My Problem:
How do I make the saveData() method work? Do I misunderstand the $.post() method? (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

I read so many forums and topics the last days but none of them solves the problem the way I´d need it, because I don´t wanna do all these difficult looking http-requests things - just reading and writing to this file that is located in the same folder then all my html and javascript Files

Thanks :)

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can not do this locally with Javascript. The $.post function is used to send data to a url.

Comment: I know that in browsers Javascript cant access local Files due to security reasons but when the file is located where my webpage is, that shouldnt be a problem, should it? I thought the URL can also be a path , same for the get Method where it works ...

Comment: Of course that's a problem... the browser only has a.. uh, *copy* of said file. The original file is still on the server; the client can't change it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$.post` is for sending a POST http request.

Client-side javascript doesn't have permission to write to a client machine.
This would be a massive security hole if it did.

**However**

You've tagged node.js in your question, which can write to the local filesystem:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("testFile.txt", "New Content of the File", function(err) {
    //done
});
```

Comment: nodejs is server side. 'normal javascript' is client side. They're two different things.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you're asking these kind of questions, you really haven't "looked through so many beginners tutorials"